# Updating connection info for Singleton repositories that have aleady be given the data during construction injection

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, castle-windsor

I am in need of an ideal solution to solve a multitenant problem with an existing Repository-esque solution.

To provide endpoint and database connection info to all repositories I have developed the following interface.

**Configuration Service Interface**

```
public interface IConfigurationService
{
    List<AvailableSystem> GetAvailableSystems();
    AvailableSystem GetCurrentSystem();
    void SetCurrentSystem(AvailableSystem system);
    AvailableSystem GetSystem(string systemID);
    void SaveSystem(AvailableSystem system);
}
```

**Configuration Service**

```
public class ConfigurationService
{
    private readonly IConfigurationService service;

    public ConfigurationService(IConfigurationService service)
    {
        if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ConfigurationService");
        this.service = service;
    }

    public List<AvailableSystem> GetAvailableSystems() { return this.service.GetAvailableSystems(); }
    public AvailableSystem GetCurrentSystem() { return this.service.GetCurrentSystem(); }
    public void SetCurrentSystem(AvailableSystem system) { this.service.SetCurrentSystem(system); }
    public AvailableSystem GetSystem(string systemID) { return this.service.GetSystem(systemID); }
    public void SaveSystem(AvailableSystem system) { this.service.SaveSystem(system); }
}
```

**Sample implementation of a Configuration Service**

```
public class ConfigFileConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
{
   //Code omitted for berevity
}
```

**Sample Config file used by the ConfigFileConfigurationService**

```
<AvailableSystems>

  <SYS_2013>               
  </SYS_2013>

  <SYS_2014>
  </SYS_2014>   

</AvailableSystems>
```

In the initial design the proper `ConfigurationService` was Registered based on logic during the system login process. In order to reduce complexity all data related repositories received an `IConfigurationService` via constructor injection because the `ConfigurationService` is always the first class registered.

**Application Buildup**

```
static public class SystemSetup
{
    public static void SetupServices(string systemID, string remoteSystemID)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("systemID",systemID));
        kvp.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("remoteSystemID",remoteSystemID));
        AppServiceFactory.Instance.RegisterTypeSingleton<IConfigurationService>(typeof(ConfigurationService),"SystemService",kvp);

        //The classes below are designed to require a IConfigurationService parameter 
        //That interface will be injected with the ConfigurationService registered above 
        AppServiceFactory.Instance.RegisterTypeSingleton<ISomeServiceA>(typeof(SomeServiceA), "SomeServiceA");
        AppServiceFactory.Instance.RegisterTypeSingleton<ISomeServiceB>(typeof(SomeServiceB), "SomeServiceB");
        ...
    }
}
```

**Sample Resource Implementation of a Data Repository class using LINQ**

```
public class ReportDataService : IReportDataService
{
    internal ReportDataDataContext _dataContext = null;
    protected IConfigurationService _systemService;

    public ReportDataService(IConfigurationService systemService)
    {
        _systemService = systemService;
        _dataContext = new ReportDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().ReadOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString);
        _dataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Now for the problem I am facing**

I apologize for the long wall of code above I wanted to be thorough. Now for my issue.

In a nutshell.

1. A `systemID` is determined when the application loads.
2. `SystemSetup` is called registering the ConfigurationSystem and all
   repositories of type singleton.
3. All data repositories connect using `new
   ReportDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().ReadOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString);`

A new requirement has been added that requires one or more of the repositories to support connecting to multiple systems after the initial setup. Since I want to continue using singleton instance for all repositories I can't simply change the `systemID` after the setup.

I also thought about registering a new IConfigurationService for repositories when they need to connect to another system :

```
AppServiceFactory.Instance.RegisterTypeSingleton<IConfigurationService>(typeof(ConfigurationService),"SystemService_ANOTHER_SYSTEM_NAME",kvp);
```

However, I would have to teardown all registered services and build them up again with the new ConfigurationService for their constructors. There are two big problems with this
The teardown/buildup is wasteful

1. I would then have to again teardown/buildup and then a second teardown/buildup when I am done with the call, again  wasteful.
2. A errand call could be made somewhere that should be connecting to the system registered during login and not the hacked system to get one damn repository method to not use the one it was constructed with.
3. If something goes wrong and the services are not reverted back to the default configurationService
   and that condition goes unchecked then all repositories will pull data from an invalid data source.
4. I feel the above is a complete hack.

I hope this made sense to someone and they can across an issue where all repositories where set up to use one repository but then had to support other systems for specific method calls. I know there is are clever solutions that would require little refactoring.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a mark on your code :

```
public ConfigurationService(IConfigurationService service)
{
    if (service == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ConfigurationService");
    this.service = service;
}
```

Do not use guard clauses because they will never get hit. If Castle can not find the dependency while trying to resolve it will throw you an exception. ["Constructor Injection should be simple."](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/)

Now for your problem. As far as I can understand you want to provide the "Conenction parameters"->"Connection String"->"Connection" chain (lets call it **ConnStringChain**) to the ReportDataService with "_systemService.GetCurrentSystem()" which is impossible because it gets only the currently configured system(ConnStringChain inside probably?). Am I right?:

```
public ReportDataService(IConfigurationService systemService)
{
    _systemService = systemService;
    _dataContext = new ReportDataDataContext(_systemService.GetCurrentSystem().ReadOnlyDatabase.ConnectionString);
    _dataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
}
```

What you need to do is to provide the ConnString chain through a component/service which is "context aware" - a component which can extract information from the current HttpContext (in case of ASP.NET MVC ) or other context object that you have - An object which knows who makes the call, through which Controller/Srevices the call comes, where is it heading(another db probably).

By having "multitenancy" as a new requirement you have actually a requirement for one additional level of indirection wich is solved by additional level of abstraction. This will change the way of object graph resolution.

This will lead you to something like this :

```
public ReportDataService(IDataContextProvider dataContextProvider)
{
    _systemService = systemService;
    _dataContextProvider = dataContextProvider;
    _dataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
}
```

You will then have your IReportDataService implementation have its public methods like this :

```
public Report CreateThisReport(...)
{
    var aThingFromContext = this._dataContextProvider.CurrentDataContext.SomeCollection...;
    ... your work.
}
```

Now your IDataContextProvider must be a [typed factory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). You can implement it as a factory method either. Your choice.

We made it this way with ASP.NET MVC and EntityFramework - We have the contraint of the Controllers lifecycle - PerRequest. But we implemented the services and repositories as singletons while caching the dbmodels and constructing the Connection and the DbContext on every request on the fily.

I hope this was clear enough. :)

Comment: Thanks! You understand my problem offer a great solution. I was thinking how can this be achieved without another level of abstraction while following best practices and the answer is that it can not.